# Passing std::vector of wrapper of std::variant into variadic class, wrapping variadic method without knowing the specifics

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

## The goal

I try to create a set of classes that removes boilerplate code for implementing extensions to a game in C++.
For that, I have a designated `value` class, that can hold one of the following types:
`float`, `std::string`, `bool`, `std::vector<value>`, `void`

For that, I would like to have a `host` class to which I can add one or more `method` instances like follows:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
host h;
h.add(
    method<bool, req<std::string>, req<std::string>, opt<bool>>("compare_strings"s,
        [](std::string s_orig, std::string s_comp, std::optional<bool> ingore_case) -> bool {
            if (ignore_case.has_value() && ignore_case.value()) {
                // ... lowercase both
            }
            return s_orig.compare(s_comp) == 0;
        }));
```

Note that `req<T>` should be a meta info that a given value is required, `opt<T>` a meta info that a given value is not required and may only be provided after all required parameters.

The `host` class now contains a method `execute(std::string function, std::vector<value> values)` with `function` and `values` originating from a method getting `char*` for method and ´char** argv`+` int argc`for values. The`execute`method now is supposed to call the correct`method` instances function

```
value host::execute(std::string function, std::vector<value> values) {
    // get matching method group
    std::vector<method> mthds = m_methods[function];
    
    // get matching parameter list
    for (method& mthd : mthds) {
        if (mthd.can_call(mthds, values)) {
            // call generic method
            auto res = mthd.call_generic(values);
            
            // pass result back to callee
            // return [...]
        }
    }
    // return error back to callee
    // return [...]
}
```

which means that the actual `method` class now needs to mangle two methods properly `can_call` and `call_generic`.

The `value` class has corresponding `template<typename T> bool is()` and `template<typename T> T get()` methods.

## What remains

I did have other attempts at this, but as those failed, I deleted them (not very smart in hindside, but needed to get the whole thing out as another person relied on the results working) and now cannot figure out another attempt then prior ... so this is what I am left with as of now:

```
class method_base
{
public:
    template<typename T> struct in { using type = T; };
    template<typename T> struct opt { using type = T; };
public:
    virtual bool can_call(std::vector<sqf::value> values) = 0;
    virtual sqf::value call_generic(std::vector<sqf::value> values) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename ... TArgs>
class method : public method_base
{
    func m_func;

    sqf::value val
public:
    using func = T(*)(TArgs...);
    method(func f) : m_func(f) {}


    virtual retval can_call(std::vector<sqf::value> values) override
    {

    }
};
```

## Appendix

If something is unclear, confusing or you just have further questions, please do ask them. I will try my best to rephrase whatever is unclear as this will help greatly with developing further extensions in the future, possibly defining a "go to" way for how to create extensions in the community for the game in question (Arma 3 just in case somebody wondered)

I may note that this is pretty much my first deep dive into meta programming so things I present may not be possible at all. If so, I kindly would like to ask you if you may also explain why that is so and the thing I attempt is not possible.

---

## The Solution

I do want to express my thanks to all who answered this question again. I ended up combining pretty much parts of all solutions here and pretty much learned a lot on the way. The final implementation I ended up with looks like the following:

```
namespace meta
{
    template <typename ArgType>
    struct is_optional : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T>
    struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type {};
    template <typename ArgType>
    inline constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_optional<ArgType>::value;

    template <typename ArgType>
    struct def_value { static ArgType value() { return {}; } };

    template <typename ArgType>
    struct get_type { using type = ArgType; };
    template <typename ArgType>
    struct get_type<std::optional<ArgType>> { using type = ArgType; };
}
struct method {
    std::function<bool(const std::vector<value>&)> m_can_call;
    std::function<value(const std::vector<value>&)> m_call;

    template <typename ... Args, std::size_t... IndexSequence>
    static bool can_call_impl(const std::vector<value>& values, std::index_sequence<IndexSequence...> s) {
        // values max args
        return values.size() <= sizeof...(Args) && 
            // for every Arg, either...
            (... && (
            // the value provides that argument and its the correct type, or...
            (IndexSequence < values.size() && sqf::is<sqf::meta::get_type<Args>::type>(values[IndexSequence])) ||
            // the value does not provide that argument and the arg is an optional
            (IndexSequence >= values.size() && sqf::meta::is_optional_v<Args>)
            ));
    }

    template <typename Ret, typename ... Args, std::size_t... IndexSequence>
    static value call_impl(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f, const std::vector<value>& values, std::index_sequence<IndexSequence...>) {
        return {
            // call the function with every type in the value set,
            // padding with empty std::optionals otherwise
            std::invoke(f,
                (IndexSequence < values.size() ? sqf::get<sqf::meta::get_type<Args>::type>(values[IndexSequence])
                                    : sqf::meta::def_value<Args>::value())...)
        };
    }

public:
    template <typename Ret, typename ... Args>
    method(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f) :
        m_can_call([](const std::vector<value>& values) -> bool
            {
                return can_call_impl<Args...>(values, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
            }),
        m_call([f](const std::vector<value>& values) -> value
            {
                return call_impl<Ret, Args...>(f, values, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
            })
    {
    }

    bool can_call(const std::vector<value>& values) const { return m_can_call(values); }

    value call_generic(const std::vector<value>& values) const { return m_call(values); }

    // to handle lambda
    template <typename F>
    method static create(F f) { return method{ std::function{f} }; }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming a way to check current type of value (`template <typename T> bool value::isA<T>()`) and a way to retrieve the value (`template <typename T> /*const*/T& get(/*const*/ value&)`)

It seems you might do:

```
struct method
{
    template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
    method(std::function<Ret(Ts...)> f) : method(std::index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>(), f)
    {}

    template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
    method(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::function<Ret(Ts...)> f) :
        isOk([](const std::vector<value>& values) {
            return ((values.size() == sizeof...(Is)) && ... && values[Is].isA<Ts>());
        }),
        call([f](const std::vector<value>& values){
            return f(get<Ts>(values[Is])...);
        })
    {}

    // to handle lambda
    template <typename F>
    static fromCallable(F f) { return method{std::function{f}}; }

    std::function<bool(const std::vector<value>&)> isOk;
    std::function<value(const std::vector<value>&)> call;
};
```

Comment: Mind to explain what is going on exactly here? Trying to understand how this approach exactly works at every step taken to be able to possibly extend the feature-set in the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I create 2 `std::function` from the function. Using indexes sequence trick to have index for vector. `optional` should be handled in `isA` and `get`.

Comment: thought more about syntactic suggar like this: `return (values.size() == sizeof...(Is) && ... && values[Is].isA<Ts>());` as that remains pretty much a mystery to me as of now. Like, what is happening with that `&& ... &&` for example?

Comment: Look at [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: Many thanks, did not was aware of how the naming scheme for that was. Gonna tick or add new comment with further questions relating to this answer tomorrow, after implementing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example including the machinery for `ret<T>` and `opt<T>`. You haven't given any information on what `value` is, so I'm going to assume something like:

```cpp
struct value {
    // using `std::monostate` instead of `void`
    std::variant<float, std::string, bool, std::vector<value>, std::monostate> data;
};
```

(I'm assuming [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) for this answer.)

From there, we need our metatypes and a few traits to branch off them. I implement them using partial specialisations, but there are other ways too.

```cpp
// types to determine optional vs. required
template <typename T>
struct req { using type = T; };
template <typename T>
struct opt { using type = T; };

// trait to determine if it's an optional type
template <typename ArgType>
struct is_optional : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_optional<opt<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename ArgType>
inline constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_optional<ArgType>::value;

// get the "real" function parameter type
template <typename ArgType>
struct real_type;
template <typename ArgType>
using real_type_t = typename real_type<ArgType>::type;
template <typename T>
struct real_type<req<T>> { using type = T; };
template <typename T>
struct real_type<opt<T>> { using type = std::optional<T>; };
```

Now we implement `method`. I'll use a similar polymorphic relationship with `method_base` as you do in your partial demo; I also template on the function type passed in, to allow e.g. the functions to use const references to the type instead of the type itself.

The implementation itself uses the common trick of delegating to helper functions with `std::index_sequence` and fold expressions to "iterate" through the variadic template args.

```cpp
// base class for polymorphism
struct method_base {
    virtual ~method_base() = default;
    virtual bool can_call(const std::vector<value>& values) const = 0;
    virtual value call_generic(const std::vector<value>& values) const = 0;
};

// provide a different method implementation for each set of args
// I also overload on 
template<typename RetType, typename Fn, typename... Args>
struct method : method_base {
private:
    Fn func;
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<RetType, Fn, real_type_t<Args>...>,
                  "function must be callable with given args");
    
public:
    // accept any function that looks sort of like what we expect;
    // static assert above makes sure it's sensible
    template <typename G>
    method(G&& func) : func(std::forward<G>(func)) {}
    
    template <std::size_t... Is> 
    bool can_call_impl(const std::vector<value>& values, std::index_sequence<Is...>) const {
        // for every Arg, either...
        return (... and (
            // the value provides that argument and its the correct type, or...
            (Is < values.size() and std::holds_alternative<typename Args::type>(values[Is].data))
            // the value does not provide that argument and the arg is an optional
            or (Is >= values.size() and is_optional_v<Args>)
        ));
    }
    
    bool can_call(const std::vector<value>& values) const override {
        return can_call_impl(values, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }
    
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    value call_generic_impl(const std::vector<value>& values, std::index_sequence<Is...>) const {
        return {
            // call the function with every type in the value set,
            // padding with empty std::optionals otherwise
            std::invoke(func, 
                (Is < values.size() ? std::get<typename Args::type>(values[Is].data) 
                                    : real_type_t<Args>{})...)
        };
    }
    
    value call_generic(const std::vector<value>& values) const override {
        return call_generic_impl(values, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }
};
```

I'll also create a helper function to make `method`s:

```cpp
template <typename RetType, typename... Args, typename Fn>
std::unique_ptr<method_base> make_method(Fn&& func) {
    return std::make_unique<method<RetType, std::decay_t<Fn>, Args...>>(std::forward<Fn>(func));
}
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d0f04dcc6223453)

It's not perfect, but this should give you a general idea of how to do it.

Comment: I am also very thankful for your answer, will check it out tomorrow properly though as it is quite a lot and i already have made my way to bed. And indeed, value is pretty much that with a few extra methods relating to parsing etc. which was why i did not specify it any further.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to:

```
method< R(Args...) >
```

your tags seem useless.  Detect optional with ... `std::optional`.

For storage, use std variant.  Use some non-void type for void (I don't care what).

As a first pass we aim for perfect compatibility.

```
template<class...Args>
struct check_signature {
  bool operator()( std::span<value const> values ) const {
    if (sizeof...(Args) != values.size()) return false;
    std::size_t i=0;
    return (std::holds_alternative<Args>(values[i++])&&...);
  }
};
```

this can be stored in a `std::function<bool(std::span<value const>)>` or just called in your class impementation.

Similar code can store the callable.

```
template<class F, class R, class...Args>
struct execute {
  F f;
  template<std::size_t...Is>
  R operator()( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::span<value const> values ) const {
    if (sizeof...(Args) != values.size()) return false;
    return f( std::get<Args>(values[Is])... );
  }
  R operator()( std::span<value const> values ) const {
    return (*this)( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{}, values );
  }
};
```

some work may have to be done for the fake `void`.

Your method is now a aggregate.

```
struct method {
  std::function<bool(std::span<value const>)> can_call;
  std::function<value(std::span<value const>)> execute;
};
```

if you want it to be.  The two template objects above can be stored in these two std functions.

There are probably tpyos, I just wrote this on my phone and have not tested it.

Extending this to cover optional args is a little bit of work.  But nothing hard.

In both cases, you'll write a helper function that says if the argument is compatible or generates the value based on if you are past the end of the incoming vector.

Ie, `std::get<Args>(values[Is])...` becomes `getArgFrom<Is, Args>{}(values)...`, and we specialize for std optional producing nullopt if `Is>values.size()`.

Comment: it is kinda correct that the tags are pretty useless as of now.. however, they mostly serve temporary usage purpose. In the future, i would like to expand on their capabilities which is why their inclusion was important :) I also thank you for your answer. Checking them in depth after work today.

Comment: *"There are probably tpyos"* You like that one ^_^.

Comment: @jarod42 It is a C++ tradition; read the early part of C++ standard drafts.